# React Router v4 How to <Link> replace only when pathname change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use react-router v4 make menu navigation

**Example Code**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/about">About</Link>
</BrowserRouter>
// ...
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />    
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

**Problem**

This code work correctly, But every time I click on a Link. BrowserHistory alway have push new location That make browser back/forward not properly.

Ex. When I click on a Home for 5 times it should be just push 1 time and replace for 4 times

Problem only when using BrowserRouter (HashRouter works properly)

[Ex: BrowserRouter](https://codepen.io/ollydbgz/pen/gRGRQg)
[Ex: HashRouter](https://codepen.io/ollydbgz/pen/Ngagow)

I want to do Link replace only when path not change.
Is possible? Is there a simple way to do?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the link to replace the current entry in the history stack you should use the `replace` attribute on the `<Link />` component.

Check this for more info:  https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/replace-bool

Check this discussion on github: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3776

Comment: I want to do Link replace only when path not change. Is possible?

Comment: replace is a bool, you can set it to true or false based on your case

Comment: I know that, But i want to know how do i check next path and prev path to make replace condition work. I'm sorry if my question is not clear. // question updated

Comment: I thought it was going to be something like onClick={() => router.replace('/about')}. But this is neat!